# ODE system with non-constant coefficients solving method?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE system:
$$\begin{cases}
t^2x'(t)-ty'(t)+y(t)=0\\
-tx(t)+y'(t) +y(t) = 2t; \,\,\,\,t>0
\end{cases}$$

I tried to solve that with annihilator (differential operator) method, but i only learnt when coefficients are constant. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

From the second equation, extract $x(t)$. Compute $x'(t)$ and replace in the first equation. You should get a very simple second order differential equation for $y(t)$. Solve it and reuse the second equation to obtain $x(t)$.